# Regex to extract multiple different words from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex that gives me something of the format:

"Core i7 Extreme Edition" or "Core i3" or "Atom" or "Pentium", given the following inputs:

"Intel® Core™ i7-6950X Processor Extreme Edition", "Intel® Core™ i3-6300T      Processor", "Intel® Atom™ Processor D2550 " or "Intel® Pentium® Processor G4400" or "Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E6400" or "Intel® Core™2 Extreme Processor QX6800" or "Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q9400S".

I want to read the special identifying features from the product name.

I realise that something along the lines of this:
Core|i3|i5|i7|Atom|Pentium|\s4\s|Celeron|Extreme Edition

Will give me what I want in a perfect world, where nothing is added.

It is possible to create it?
If it adds anything I am using C# but it is in an environment that is very generic and I only have the string and the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex: (See on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wn7A6y/2))

```
Intel® | Processor|®|™|[ -][A-Z]*\d{4}[A-Z]*
```

And replace with empty string `""`. This matches all non-wanted parts and removes them.

```
string pattern = @"Intel® | Processor|®|™|[ -][A-Z]*\d{4}[A-Z]*";
string substitution = @"";
string input = @"Intel® Core™ i7-6950X Processor Extreme Edition";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
```

Comment: Almost works perfectly, but I have one "edge" case where it misses the number "2" after ™ in, "Intel® Core™2 Quad Processor Q9400S".

Comment: http://prntscr.com/dc0w9c from regex101 

http://prntscr.com/dc0wkx from debug example in Visual studio. 

I must be doing something wrong compared to you then?

Comment: Oh you mean you want to keep the number 2?

Comment: Yes this is specifically a part of the identifiication of the product. 

Sorry if it was unclear.